# "errorMessage": "name ' ' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I would like to create a report in Lambda using Python that is saved in a CSV file. So you will find the code of the function:

```
import boto3
import re
import csv

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    client = boto3.client('ce')
    response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={
            'Start': "2019-02-01",
            'End':  "2019-08-01"
        },
        Granularity='MONTHLY',
        Metrics=['BlendedCost'],
        GroupBy=[
            {
                'Type': 'TAG',
                'Key': 'Project'
            },
        ]
    )

    temp_csv_file = csv.writer(open("/tmp/csv_file.csv", "w+"))
    # writing the column names
    temp_csv_file.writerow(["Account Name", "Month", "Cost"])

    # writing rows in to the CSV file
    for detail in participant_details:
        temp_csv_file.writerow([response['account_name'],
                                response['month'],
                                response['cost']
                                ])

    client = boto3.client('s3')
    client.upload_file('/tmp/csv_file.csv', BUCKET_NAME,'final_report.csv')
```

How can I fix the following error?

```
"errorMessage": "name 'participant_details' is not defined",
```

Comment: `for detail in participant_details:` what is participant_details? Where do you define it?

Comment: @sertsedat so it should be response instead participant_details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, you haven't defined the variable `participant_details` so its value cannot be looked up. You should define that variable first before accessing it.

Comment: so it should be response instead participant_details?

Comment: It depends on what `client.get_cost_and_usage` does. Can you edit the question to show an example of what you expect `response` to contain after you make that call?